# CMake command using Jetbrain's CMake works, but fails with original CMake

Tags: windows, cmake, clion

I have a CLion project and I wish to configure and build it in command line.

The following command (in powershell) works:
`& "C:/Users/[username]/AppData/Local/Programs/CLion Nova/bin/cmake/win/x64/bin/cmake.exe" "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug" "-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:/Users/[username]/AppData/Local/Programs/CLion Nova/bin/ninja/win/x64/ninja.exe" -G Ninja -S [source dir] -B [build dir]`

Simply using original CMake (same version), causes the command to fail with `LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'kernel32.lib'`.

Does anyone know what Jetbrain's CMake is doing differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JetBrains CLion might use a specific CMake generator that sets up the project differently. In your standalone CMake command, you're using the Ninja generator, which should work. However, you can try using a different generator, such as "Visual Studio" or "Visual Studio 16 2019" if they are available on your system:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -S [source dir] -B [build dir]
```

replace "Visual Studio 16 2019" with the appropriate generator name for your system.

Comment: Thanks, it does seems to work, but I don't understand why. In CLion, I am using VS toolchain (i.e. cl.exe), and ninja generator, why the ninja generator works with CLion's cmake and not with the standalone CMake?

Comment: CLion's CMake integration differs due to internal customization, handling toolchains, and managing CMake generators like Ninja. It abstracts the build environment and configures variables and caches uniquely, which can lead to differences when using standalone CMake from the command line, especially with library locations. Understanding these distinctions is crucial for project configuration.